# Listen to a click on a root item of a menu bar (Vaadin)

Tags: listener, vaadin, menubar, clicklistener

Simple and short question, but I'm not so sure about a good answer. ;)

Is it somehow possible to add a Listener to the root items of a menu bar?

[image: Menu Bar]

I'd like to click the Edit item and a event should be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vaadin API documentation](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.MenuItem.html) :

> You can set commands to be fired on user click by implementing the MenuBar.Command interface.

Create a class that implements MenuBar.Command interface and then add the root item by calling [MenuBar.addItem](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.html#addItem%28java.lang.String,%20com.vaadin.ui.MenuBar.Command%29)

You can also skip the class creation like this:

```
myMenuBar.addItem("My Item", new MenuBar.Command() {
    void menuSelected(MenuBar.MenuItem selectedItem) {
        // Handle selection
    }
});
```

Comment: When I saw that answer at first I thought, this does not work because it was exactly the code I had. But trying the code again, showed that the problem has been somewhere else, because now it works as expected. Nevertheless thanks for the answer. ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing in xaml, can't you just do in the element, something like `<Menu... OnClick="...">`

Comment: I'm not doing anything in xaml. The UI is written in Java which is compiled to Javascript by the GWT Compiler. But changing the javascript does not work straight forward.